What are these black lines along the bottom of the exterior walls?
I noticed that there are these black lines along the bottom of the exterior walls of a new build. They don't feel like cracks and the black part is softer to touch than the concrete wall. Does anyone know what they are?
Thank you!

The black waterproofing was painted on too high onto the foundation wall, and when the foundation wall was painted to hide it, it was not a compatible finish for the waterproofing on the concrete and it shows that by the vieny, crack like separations you see. It is purly estetic.
